# Python Selenium - URL won't open in browser instance

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webbrowser-control

This particular [URL](http://www.examiners.state.al.us/ReportSearch.aspx) won't open via python selenium script below. This same code works for most of the urls I have tried it on.

```
chrome_driver = 'chromedriver.exe' # Change this to your chrome driver path 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
driver.get(url)
```

There is no any error message displayed, it will only show blank page and nothing will happen. When manually typed into regular chrome browser, it opens correctly but when manually into chrome browser instance, it won't work just like the script.

What is the solution to fix this?

Comment: Please include the code where `url` is defined. Also, make sure your chromedriver and selenium are updated to the latest versions. Outdated/incompatible versions is a common cause of this problem.

Comment: It's possible that the `url` does not have the http or https prefix that is required in selenium, but browsers will do things for you when entering things manually in their url bar.